# Why is this program not working and i think the error is in linked list assignment?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
   struct sam{
     int data;
     struct sam *next;
   };
   struct sam node[11];
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   node[i].data = i/2;
   node[i].next = &node[i+1];
 }
 node[10].next=NULL;
 for  (size_t i = 0;node[i].next!=NULL; i++) {
 std::cout  <<node[i].data<< '\t';
 }
 std::cout  << '\n';
 for(int i=0;node[i].next->next!=NULL;i++){
   if(node[i].data == node[i].next->data){
   node[i].next = node[i].next->next;
 }
}

for (size_t i = 0;node[i].next!=NULL; i++) {
std::cout << "Data is " <<node[i].data<< '\t';
}
return 0;
}
```

The objective is to Remove duplicates from a sorted linked list
And I've randomly allocated 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 to the list
The line node[i].next = node[i].next->next is not executing and henceforth I'm not getting desired output...

Comment: **C** doesn't even have `std::cout` - that's C++ there. Also: [debugging](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: I recommend indenting your code properly, many an error has been found by applying a coding helpful coding style.

Comment: You do not use next to go over the list. You always iterate over underlying array - and it never changes

Comment: Artemy seems right. What makes you think that the line is not executed? @ArtemyVysotsky, would you like to make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original node array

```
     +-------------------------------------------------+
data | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | Garbage |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
Next   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10    NULL
```

After setting next

```
     +-------------------------------------------------+
data | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | Garbage |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
Next   2   2   4   4   6   6   8   8   10   10    NULL
```

So if you go from head node to the next using next pointer - you'll see filtered list

But since you go using original indexed approach - you still see all nodes.

I have shown next as Index just for illustration instead of real pointer values - So where you see Next == 2 - it means pointer goes to array member node[2]